# Отсеивание пустых значений laravel при выводе

Tags: laravel

Нужно мне нужно что бы цикл выводил только те элементы которые не равны нулю

Контроллер:

```
   public function filter() {
    
            
    $data = DB::table('filters_catalogs')->get();
    
    $filters = $data->all();
    
    return view('admin.filters.filters', [
        'filters' => $filters,
    ]);

}

             @foreach($filters as $el)
             @if ($col_1 !== "0" )
             <li class="list-group-item">
                        
                <p>{{ $el->col_1 }}</p>
                  <div style="display: flex;" id="flex-end">
                    <a href="/admin/news/{{ $el->id }}/edit" style="margin-right: 15px" class="btn btn-warning">Редактировать</a>
                    <a href="/admin/news/{{ $el->id }}/delete" type="button" style="color: white;" class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</a>
                  </div>
                  
              </li> 
             @endif
             @endforeach
```

Почему не работает что то не так с условием?

Comment: `->where('col_1')` что это такое объясните пожалуйста. И что оно значит? так же запрос на стадии подготовки, нет в конце `get`, `first` и т.д для его выполнения. Если переменная не выводится отлаживайте с помощью `dd('переменная')` и смотрите что внутри

Comment: ->where('col_1') я так понимаю что заносит в переменную значение именно col_1 из таблицы

Comment: `->where('col_1') я так понимаю что заносит в переменную значение именно col_1 из таблицы` - неправильно вы понимаете. [Вот зачем используется where](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#simple-where-clauses).

Comment: Исправил, у вас есть идеи по выводу значение не равных нулю и в blade это вообще делается или нет

Comment: теперь `$col_1` - это переменная не определена. `@foreach($filters as $el)` - в blade есть `@continue`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45189574/9435985. А вообще что за условие `те элементы которые не равны нулю`? `$data->all();` возвращает пустые элементы? Нет. Тогда что имеется в виду? Потом `$data = DB::table('filters_catalogs')->get()->all();` - зачем тут еще `all()`? Уберите all

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй
@if ($col_1 !== "0" ) на
@if ($el->col_1 !== "0" )

Answer (score 0):

```
public function filter() {     
   $filters = DB::table('filters_catalogs')->where('col_1', '<>', 0)->get();  
   return view('admin.filters.filters', [
       'filters' => $filters,
   ]);
```

}

```
         @foreach($filters as $el)
         <li class="list-group-item">
            <p>{{ $el->col_1 }}</p>
              <div style="display: flex;" id="flex-end">
                <a href="/admin/news/{{ $el->id }}/edit" style="margin-right: 15px" class="btn btn-warning">Редактировать</a>
                <a href="/admin/news/{{ $el->id }}/delete" type="button" style="color: white;" class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</a>
              </div>
          </li> 
         @endif
         @endforeach
```